# Install Python 3.2.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, installation

I have Python 3.2.2 downloaded and have been using IDLE to execute code; however, I was wondering whether it is possible to have Python 3.2.2 run through Terminal as opposed to Python 2.6.1 on which it is currently running.

How would I got about doing so? Would there be any bad side effects?

Comment: I highly recommend installing pythonbrew and virtualenv if you might ever need different versions of python in the same machine. They'll save you A LOT of time.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, start the terminal and type `python3.2`. That should get you into a Python 3.2 shell.

Answer (score 0):

No side effects, you can also use `alias python3="/directory/where/python_binary"` to get python3 as an shortcut to real python binary.